# How do I know if jndi lookup is working in Spring Boot or not

Tags: oracle, web-services, spring-boot, tomcat7, jndi

In my Spring Boot web application, I specified the jndi datasource name in application.properties (src/main/resources) together with other database parameters.

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/ristoreDataService
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Before I deploy it in Apache Tomcat, I edited context.xml in {apache-tomcat}/conf by adding the following:

```
<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/ristoreDataSource" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://mdaoid.xxx.org:389/risstg3, cn=OracleContext,dc=xxcc,dc=tmc,dc=org"
          username="db_owner" password="dbpass" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
          maxWait="-1"/>
```

However, the deploy failed. I found the following error in catalina.log file indicating db connection is not successful.

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ristoreService]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Did I set it up right? How do I know if jdni lookup is working or not?

This line `<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>` was in the context.xml originally. But Spring Boot application does not have a web.xml, could that be what's causing the trouble?

Comment: @Alex I don't think so. There are tons of posts out there with the same error. However the setup is definitely different. I used to have everything declared in my application.properties just like the answer of that post and it worked just fine. Now I've moved the db information to external configuration (context.xml) and am using jndi look-up